# EditTexts are always empty when clicking OK

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

When I click OK the Strings returned are always empty strings `""`. They aren't, could the problem be that the dialog is created twice so they're not referring to the same `EditTexts`?

```
package com.example.gaetano.notebook;


public class AddNoteFragment extends DialogFragment`enter code here`{

public EditText title;
public EditText note;
public OnNoteAdded noteAdded;

public interface OnNoteAdded {
    void onNoteAdded(Note note);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    noteAdded = (OnNoteAdded) activity;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_note, null);

    title = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edTitle);
    note = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edNote);

    builder.setTitle("Add a new note");
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_note, null))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.add_note, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    String t = title.getText().toString();
                    String n = note.getText().toString();

                    Note note = new Note(t, n , false);
                    noteAdded.onNoteAdded(note);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    AddNoteFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

When clicking OK the EditTexts are always empty "".

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_note, null);

title = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edTitle);
note = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edNote);
```

Then in my `setPositiveButton, OnClick` method I get the Strings of these texts. By doing this `String t = title.getText().toString();
 String n = note.getText().toString();`
They always return `""`

In the MainActivity I then implement the interface like this `@Override
    public void onNoteAdded(Note note) {
        noteAdapter.add(note);
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Layout Inflater API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup)), Inflater's `inflate()`  method returns a `View` object. You can hold the `reference` of this `View` object in a variable, which will act as a `root view` for the Dialog's screen.Using this `root view`, you can find all the child views contained in this `root view's tree` or simply, which are children of this root view using `findViewById()`.

Here is the snippet for `onCreateDialog()`:-

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_note, null)
Button mydialogbutton=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_dialog_button);
            //Button is exemplary but this is how you can access any child component of the root view

builder.setTitle("Add a new note");
builder.setView(rootView)
.setPositiveButton(R.string.add_note, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        Note newNote = new Note(
            "hey",
            "notehey",
            false);
        noteAdded.onNoteAdded(newNote);
    }
})
.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        AddNoteFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
    }
});
return builder.create();
```

The process to create and reference the view is same to that of onCreateView(). As in both `onCreateDialog()` and `onCreateView()`, you are using Layout Inflater to get a reference to the `View` object.

Comment: Thank you it works now! Didn't knew it was the same process as onCreateView()!

Comment: When I use the rootView to my EditTexts they are always empty?

Comment: Please be more clear in your explanation or share the code snippet. you can edit your question for this purpose

Comment: Share the complete activity code. The code is incomplete, the way I am seeing it. Another reason can be that your edit texts are probably empty. Do not confuse hint with text.

Comment: instead of this, builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_note, null)) use this, builder.setView(rootView)

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that too! Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: Yeah, those two are two different instances of the View object, They are not same.